# jQuery Validation Problems Using equalTo

Tags: jquery, validation

I'm doing a pretty simple validation that checks if two fields are equal. Unfortunately, it seems to not be working (returns false when it should return true).

Here's the jQuery (#profSet is the main form):

```
            //if either password field is filled, start trying to validate it
            if($("#chpw").val() != "" || $("#chpw2").val() != "")
            {
                $("#profSet").validate({
                    rules: {
                        chpw2: {
                            equalTo: "#chpw"
                        }
                    }
                });
                if($("#profSet").valid())
                {
                    $pv = 1;
                }
                else
                {
                    $pv = 0;
                }
            }
```

Here's the HTML:

```
    <tr>
        <td>Change Password</td><td><input type="password" id="chpw" name="chpw"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Confirm Password</td><td><input type="password" id="chpw2" name="chpw2"/><br><label for="chpw2" class="error" generated="true"></label></td>
  </tr>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I suppose something like

[UPDATE]: Sorry for hypothetical answer

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function (){
    $('#form').validate({

        rules:{
            chpw:{
                required: true,
                equalTo: '#chpw2'
            }

        },

        messages:{
            chpw: 
                {
                required: "Password is required",
                equalTo: "Password must be equal"
                }

        }}
    )

})


</script>

<form id="form">
    <tr>
    <td>Change Password</td><td><input type="password" id="chpw" name="chpw"/></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
    <td>Confirm Password</td><td><input type="password" id="chpw2" name="chpw2"/><br><label for="chpw2" class="error" generated="true"></label></td>
  </tr>
<input type="submit" name="submit" />  
</form>
```

Comment: It still doesn't validate properly, it seems to disregard what I type in.

Answer (score 2):

You can do like bellow -

```
$("#formId").validate({
        rules: {

            chpw: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 6
            },
            chpw2: {
                required: true,
                minlength: 6,
                equalTo: "#chpw"
            }
        }
    });
```

});